# Screen width CSS

Tags: html, css, web, screen

[image]

As you can see in the image my heders,dev,nav bar does not fit to my screen width i put margine and padding in to 0 but it is not working

this is my CSS code:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(9, 9, 143);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a1/99/f3/a199f37446cbe1cd6701c693963971c3.jpg');
    background-blend-mode: color-burn;
}

div{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
ul.navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #918e8e;
}

/* CSS for the active button */
ul.navbar li.active a {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.main{
    background-color: rgb(8, 8, 87);
    background-image: url('https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/290/679/HD-wallpaper-harry-potter-harry-potter-and-the-chamber-of-secrets-hogwarts-castle.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: lighten;
    display: flex-box;
    text-align: center;
 

}

h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Rockwell;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}

p{
    color: rgb(158, 169, 179);
    font-family: Franklin Gothic Medium;
    padding: 20px;
}

.btn{
    padding: 10px 5px;
    background-color: rgb(30, 30, 123);
    color: whitesmoke;
    border:  1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I hosted my web in google
here the link:[https://myassessmentweb.netlify.app](https://stackoverflow.com)

**please give me a better solution for this issue. **

Comment: Without your relevant HTML how did you want us to help, exactly? We can't reproduce your problem without enough code to reproduce the problem you describe, we can't debug a picture, and posting a link to your site is not considered appropriate (see: "[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/82548)")

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this problem you should either remove `width: 100%;` from your `h1` and `div` styles or add:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:  border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add `box-sizing: border-box` to your global selector

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:  border-box;
}
```

you can read more about box-sizing here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

here the problem is in the paddind h1(delete padding in h1), it is he who stretches the width more than the visible area and the slider appears

Comment: Nope its not Its about border boxing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width:100vw;` where `vw` is viewport width. Same goes for the height but instead of vw you use `vh`.For some of you that it still doesn't work try `margin: 0px;` because sometimes divs and other elements have default margins.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 100%`. `body` is a block element, it will take up 100% any way, but 100% doesn't account for, for example the scrollbar.
https://youtube.com/shorts/0-WRRh3ZXhw?feature=share